# How can i override module_backend file in app/design folder in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend, phtml, copyright

i need to need to change admin copyright content they comes from this

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml

so how can i override this in my app/design folder in magento 2?

[image]

Comment: you can override template in custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an admin theme and register it. The solution applies to all common Magento 2 Admin customizations that can be done by just overriding a phtml template. You will just have to copy and place the template to customize at the right location (`<theme_dir>/Magento_<MODULE>/templates/<template>.phtml`.

### Creating the admin theme

Create a admin theme directory under `app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<admin_theme_name>`.

You will have to create a theme as documented in the [Magento 2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html), if not already done. Registering the theme will need two files.

**app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<admin_theme_name>/registration.php**:

```php
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 
    'adminhtml/<Vendor>/<your_theme_name>', 
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<admin_theme_name>/theme.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Your Theme Name</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

### Overridding the copyright.phtml

When you have created an admin theme, you can now override your template. To do that, copy the original file and place it at the correct position.

Copy `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml` to `app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<admin_theme_name>/Magento_Backend/templates/page/copyright.phtml`. You can edit the template there to fit your needs (for example add some more text).

### Applying the admin theme

You must register the admin theme in a module.
Create a new module or use an existing one. The module must be loaded after the `Magento_Theme` module. You can find a reference for that in the [Magento 2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html).

**app/code/<Vendor>/<YourModule>/registration.php:**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_YourModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/<Vendor>/<YourModule>/etc/module.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_YourModule">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Finally, after creating your module files, you have to register the theme in your `di.xml`:

**app/code/<Vendor>/<YourModule>/etc/di.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/your_theme_name</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

You **must** now do a `setup:upgrade`.
Replacing the copyright or another adminhtml template without creating a module that is applying your admin theme is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom module for that :

Try following way:

Create **default.xml** at

> app/code/Your_VendorName/Your_ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

Add below code in **default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="copyright">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::copyright.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then Copy info.phtml file from

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/templates/html/copyright.phtml

To

> app/code/Your_Vendor/Your_Module/view/adminhtml/templates/copyright.phtml